# Iphone cannot receive push notification

Tags: push, apple-push-notifications

I used Javapns to push notification to iphone, when i run the test applicaiton fist time, iPhone can receive the notification, but when i tried agian, no notication will be recieveed, about 20-40 minutes after i receive the notification, i tried again, then i received it, doese any limitatoin on appler server that i can only send the notifiction after special interval?

Answer (score 0):

JavaPNS was recently updated to 2.0, and fixed ALL reported issues up to the release date.  I believe it fixes the issue you are reporting, as the problem being described seems to be caused by an un-closed or un-timed-out connection.